# How to disable scroll/swipe from FSCalendar?

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I'm using FSCalendar for iOS and would like to know if there's any way to disable the scroll to the left or right and only show the current week?

I am able to swipe right and see the next week view, whereas, I want to disable this functionality so users can only see current week dates.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add just 2 following lines where you configure your calendar and check result

```
yourCalendar.scrollEnabled = false
yourCalendar.pagingEnabled = false
```